# PHP function for converts html entities back to html special characters

Tags: php

I have this function for converts html entities back to html special characters:

```
function html_entity_decode_utf8($value, $double_encode = TRUE) 

{
    return htmlspecialchars( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", $double_encode);


}
```

Now, I need to Print this:

```
echo html_entity_decode_utf8('&amp;zwnj');
```

Output is:

```
&amp;zwnj
```

Why `htmlspecialchars` notwork ?! how i can fix this?

Comment: without looking into it, missing `&` ?

Comment: @Hannes: add `&` This Not Work.

Comment: Now you miss the first quote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` converts `&` into `&amp;`. To convert back, you need `htmlspecialchars_decode`:

```
function html_entity_decode_utf8($value) 
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

To see more options for using this function, check out [the documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).